# Can you dodge the "version mismatch" bug in Civilization V?

Tags: civilization-5

Recently, an upgrade has been made for Civilization 5, that makes it impossible for Macs and PCs to play together, due to "version mismatch" (the update was for Windows only)

This have happened before, and there have been weeks before a proper fix arrived. As far as I can tell, its simply a string comparison between the version numbers of the clients that resolve this.

Is it possible to work around this in any way? Some mean hack or opening file X with a text editor and do some magic?

We have a meeting this weekend to play the new expansion, and we are five macs and three PCs... It would be sad if we were unable to play together all of us.

Comment: Did you try changing strings in any config files? Any luck?

Comment: The issue is still very much active :(

Comment: Since it looks like no one on here actually knows the answer, you might be better off trying it out yourself with 2 copies of civ5 on different machines or finding someone with civ5 with the alternate operating system and just try different configurations. If it worked with earlier versions, there's no reason you couldn't hack it yourself and see what works. This is sometimes the only option.

Comment: The best suggestion I have is to turn off auto-update on the PCs until the MAX patch version is released.

Comment: Sadly, they have auto-upgraded (steam does this in the background) and there is no rollback options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue got resolved earlier today with a Mac patch available on Steam.

This was a long dry streak, and hopefully it will not reoccur (alas, it has occured three times now, with weeks between playability, so I don't believe it will never reoccur.)

Comment: Is this patch part of some DLC, because I have the same problem and cannot find it.

Comment: Yeah, the problem persists. I'm on a PC and my boyfriend on a Mac and we still haveing the "version mismatch" stuff.

Comment: @ForceMagic If you look at the date on this answer, you'll see that this was the July patch. You're experiencing this now because, once again, the PC version has recently updated and the Mac version hasn't.

Comment: Yes... they have done it again...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but I'm pretty sure the answer to your question is "no". Even if you managed to fake out the version check code you'd be running different versions of the game code, with different rules for units, etc. The game would quickly get out of sync.